# Switch the button action based on id of a button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, switch-statement, next.js

i'm trying to change the button redirect link based on ID, but i'm new to NEXT.JS and i don't know how to do it.
I know that this request should be made after render maybe with "useEffect" or need one variable to make somenthing like "document.GetElementsbyTagName" but how? the next.js doesn't have a "document" defined.

my example code below

```
 <ul className="home-brandstext">
                  <li><button onClick={clickHandle} id="Linkedin"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin}/> LinkedIn</button></li>
                  <li><button onClick={clickHandle} id="Github"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub}/> GitHub</button></li>
                  <li><button onClick={clickHandle} id="Instagram"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram}/> Instagram</button></li>
                  <li><button onClick={clickHandle} id="Skype"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSkype}/> Skype</button></li>
                  <li><button onClick={clickHandle} id="Whatsapp"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWhatsapp}/> WhatsApp</button></li>
                </ul>     

const clickHandle = () => {
  switch(id) {
    case 'Linkedin' : {
      document.location.href = 'https://linkedin.com/in/gustavo-morilla';
      break;
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onClick` callback receives an `event` as argument which can be used to retrieve the target element that triggered it, and subsequently get its `id`.

```js
const clickHandle = (event) => {
    switch(event.target.id) {
        case 'Linkedin' : {
            // Logic to handle `Linkedin` case
            break;
        }  
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your document using validator `process.browser` or `typeof window != 'undefined'` because nextJS is rended on server side and document is present on client side.

```
if(process.browser){
document.location.href =''
}
```

use this inside `React.useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount()` method

Comment: This is really possible! i need to study more about next.js to do that and really understand each step. So the answer above keep it simple. I will try your answer later. Thank you!!!